Trying to access CSS attribute value in JS, can't use it outside of 'DOMContentLoaded' event
I am trying to access the transition duration property of an element in my scene.
The problem is, when trying to get it without the 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener, it returns 0 or a blank string.
When using the event listener, I get the correct value, but I can't assign it to an outside variable, which I want. What could be causing this?
Remember that I need to use that value in an export function, so it can't be written inside the event listener.
const sceneContainer = document.getElementById('scene-container');
const canvas = document.getElementById("three-canvas");

let transitionDuration;
let isExpanded = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    transitionDuration = window.getComputedStyle(sceneContainer).getPropertyValue("transition-duration");
    //returns 'Inside DOMContentLoaded: | 0.5s'
    console.log("Inside DOMContentLoaded:", transitionDuration);
});

//returns undefined
console.log(transitionDuration) 

.
.
.
export function expandScreen() {...}

I tried many different things, and when I finally got to see the correct value I couldn't access it from outside.

Please add the CSS and HTML to you question so that we can replicate your issue and provide guidance.

Using a promise will fix the issue as it will make sure that the "DOMContentLoaded" is executed and you can access the CSS property.
Check the console in this CodePen of a working version of the code
Code:
<body>
<style>
    #scene-container {
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
</style>
  <div id="scene-container">Scene Container</div>
</body>

Updated JS Code:
const sceneContainer = document.getElementById('scene-container');
let transitionDuration;
let isExpanded = false;

const domContentLoadedPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    transitionDuration = window.getComputedStyle(sceneContainer).getPropertyValue("transition-duration");
    console.log("Inside DOMContentLoaded:", transitionDuration);
    resolve();
  });
});


async function ensureTransitionDuration() {
  await domContentLoadedPromise;
  return transitionDuration;
}

async function expandScreen() {
  const duration = await ensureTransitionDuration();
  console.log("Transition duration:", duration);

  if (!isExpanded) {
    sceneContainer.style.width = "100%";
    sceneContainer.style.height = "100%";
    isExpanded = true;
  } else {
    sceneContainer.style.width = "";
    sceneContainer.style.height = "";
    isExpanded = false;
  }
}

expandScreen();

I have added few dummy code for testing but you can adjust it to your needs
